# React JS - updating state within an eventListener

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update the state of my component inside of an eventListener. I'm getting the following console error:

**'Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Header component'**

This is my component code:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            fixed: false
        }
    }

    handleScroll(event) {      
        this.setState({
            fixed: true
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("scroll",() => {            
            this.handleScroll();       
        });       
    }    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll",() => {            
            this.handleScroll();       
        });   
    }


    render() {
        var {
            dispatch,
            className = "",
            headerTitle = "Default Header Title",
            onReturn,
            onContinue
        } = this.props;

        var renderLeftItem = () => {
            if (typeof onReturn === 'function') {
                return (
                    <MenuBarItem icon="navigation-back" onClick={onReturn}/>
                )
            }
        };

        var renderRightItem = () => {
              if (typeof onContinue === 'function') {
                  return (
                      <MenuBarItem icon="navigation-check" onClick= {onContinue}/>
                  )
              }
        };

        return (
            <div className={"header " + className + this.state.fixed}>
                  {renderLeftItem()}
                  <div className="header-title">{headerTitle}</div>
                      {renderRightItem()}
                  </div>
         )
     }

}


Header.propTypes = {

};

let mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO this is because you do ont unregister the function as you expect it, and a scroll event is sent after an instance of this component has been unmounted

try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this._handleScroll);       
}    
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this._handleScroll);   
}
```